# Constructing a nil-terminated NSString list as an NSString *

Tags: objective-c, ios

There are many methods in the SDK that ask for a list of strings, terminated by a nil, for example, in UIActionSheet:

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title delegate:(id < UIActionSheetDelegate >)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle destructiveButtonTitle:(NSString *)destructiveButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
```

'otherButtonTitles' in this case is a list of NSStrings terminated with a nil.  What I'd like to do is call this method with a constructed NSMutableArray of NSStrings, because I'd like to create and order the arguments dynamically.  How would I do this?  I'm not sure how to create a nil-terminated pointer to NSStrings in this case, and if passing it in would even work.  Do I have to alloc the memory for it manually and release it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You **cannot** convert any array into a variadic list.

However, for UIActionSheet, you could add those *otherButtonTitles* after the sheet is created, using [`-addButtonWithTitle:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIActionSheet/addButtonWithTitle%3a)

```
UIActionSheet* sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:...
                                                        /*etc*/
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
for (NSString* otherButtonTitle in otherButtonTitlesArray)
{
   [sheet addButtonWithTitle:otherButtonTitle];
}
```

Comment: This isn’t a good solution if you are setting a cancel button on your UIActionSheet. When you initialise the sheet and then add `otherButtons` with a loop as above, your Cancel button will end up sitting on top of them for some reason.

Comment: Should solve the problem. [sheet setCancelButtonIndex:[sheet numberOfButtons] - 1];

Comment: @mtwagner nope this only changes the style of the button - not the order in which they appear

Comment: Is there no way to create a nil-terminated String list??

Answer (score 5):

I need to make a dynamic action sheet as well. So I made a mostly empty action sheet. Added my buttons. Then added the Cancel button and marked it as cancel.

```
sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:homeName, nil];    
[sheet addButtonWithTitle:otherButton1];
[sheet addButtonWithTitle:otherButton2];
[sheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[sheet setCancelButtonIndex:[sheet numberOfButtons] - 1];
sheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
[sheet showInView:self.view];
[sheet release];
```

Comment: This a more complete answer than the accepted one.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You sure **CAN** convert NSArray to va_list. For example to use with `NSString`

```
- (id)initWithFormat:(NSString *)format arguments:(va_list)argList
```

Like this:

```
+ (id)stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format array:(NSArray *)arguments;
{
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [arguments count]);
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:sizeof(id) * [arguments count]];
    [arguments getObjects:(__unsafe_unretained id *) data.mutableBytes range:range];
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:data.mutableBytes];
}
```

Comment: it's all good to say you CAN do it, pointing to a different use case; but CAN YOU do it for the use case given by OP?

Comment: It is the comment for the first line of an accepted answer, so your comment is not necessary